# Ensure orphaned processes are killed when the parent process dies

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

In Ruby, how do I ensure that child processes spawned from my program don't keep running when my main process exits or is killed?

Initially I thought I could just use `at_exit` in the main process, but that won't work if my main process gets `kill -9`ed or calls `Kernel.exec`. I need a solution that is (basically) foolproof, and cross-platform.

Comment: How are you starting the child process in question? For instance, is it an `Open4.open4` block?

Comment: Note if your main process is `kill -9`ed then there is very little you can do in code. The person running the `kill 9` has made the decision that it is their problem to tidy up.

Comment: @NeilSlater I'm using a library ([childprocess](https://github.com/jarib/childprocess)) which uses different methods for starting the child process depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to handle kill -9 termination for your parent app, then you have only a couple of choices that I can see:

- Create a work queue manager and spawn/kill child processes from work queue manager. If you can't guarantee that the work queue manager won't also be killed without warning, then option 2 is your only choice I think, since the only thing you know for sure is that the child processes are still running.

  - http://www.celeryproject.org/
  - http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

    - More aggressive approach - basically spawn off whole OS instances but they'll definitely get killed off within your parameters for operation
- Have the child processes check a "heartbeat" from the parent process through RPC or monitoring parent PID in memory or watching a date/time on keep-alive file in /tmp to make sure it's current.

  - If the child processes fail to see the parent processes doing it's job of either responding to RPC messages, staying in memory itself, or keeping a file date/time current the child processes must kill themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I basically ended up going with option 2, except that instead of the child process directly checking the heartbeat of the parent I spawned a separate process to handle that.